# Granularity for creating VCS-Repositories

Tags: git, svn, version-control, cvs

At which granularity do you create a new VCS-Repository?

> For example we got 
>   some basic API/Library (~30 projects), some
>   development tools (~10 tools, each tool has ~5 projects) and multiple
>   applications (~20 applications with ~15 projects).   The tools and
>   applications are based on the basic library and some applications
>   might have dependencies on other applications.

I thought of creating 3 repositories

- one for the library
- one for the development tools
- and one for the applications

Would this be a meaningful separation of the code or would you recommend another granularity?

Cheers

Comment: what are "projects" here? Visual Studio projects?

Comment: It depends on how people will work with it... If used independantly then yes 3 repos is a good option, if they are tight together why bother, make one repo

Comment: I think in most cases there will be one group of developers who will maintain the basic library and the development tools. But at the application level there might be multiple groups which are working at different subsets of applications (depending on the department).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the version-control system that you use. In case of Subversion, you could have a single monolithic repository for all of your projects. For example, the [official Apache Software Foundation repository](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/) numerous projects that are under ASF umbrella. You could also follow repository per-project approach without any issues.

It's different with git, though. As it is decentralized, it can't effectively store multiple projects in one repository. You are limited to repository per-project approach.